# Fs rename is not finding the file

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
http = require("http");
fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.rename("anewfile.txt", "/folder/anewfile.txt", function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Moved file");
  });
}).listen(8000);
```

I am expecting it to move the file "anewfile.txt" which is in the same directory as my program into a folder called "folder" which is also of the same directory. However I get a "file not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `path.join(__dirname, "anewfile.txt")` as the source name instead of `"anewfile.txt"`.

The issue is that you are likely running the script from a directory that is not where the source is located. The filenames passed to `fs.rename` are resolved relative to the current working directory `process.cwd()`, not the location of the source module `__dirname`. Only `require` uses `__dirname` as its base.